# Can you Convert Stripe Java Code into CFscript

Tags: coldfusion, stripe-payments, cfml

The code below is how to impletment stripe payment API, I was wondering if I just convert it to CFscript and call my normal variable will it work?

```
    // Set your secret key: remember to change this to your live secret key in production
// See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
Stripe.apiKey = "sk_test_aHhoYVOnsayNSIleB1ETUCSq00vUOS9YVQ";

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

ArrayList<String> paymentMethodTypes = new ArrayList<>();
paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
params.put("payment_method_types", paymentMethodTypes);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> lineItems = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, Object> lineItem = new HashMap<String, Object>();
lineItem.put("name", "T-shirt");
lineItem.put("description", "Comfortable cotton t-shirt");
lineItem.put("amount", 500);
lineItem.put("currency", "usd");
lineItem.put("quantity", 1);
lineItems.add(lineItem);
params.put("line_items", lineItems);

params.put("success_url", "https://example.com/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}");
params.put("cancel_url", "https://example.com/cancel");

Session session = Session.create(params);
```

Comment: Since CF runs atop java, most java code can be converted.  See tips on [converting java to cfscript](https://cfdocs.org/java). Having said that ... "just because you *can*, doesn't mean you should".  As the answer below points out, CF already has functionality for making http calls. So you probably don't need an external java library for this task at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not a direct conversion of the Java code you've provided above, it should be fairly straight-forward to do this with `cfscript` using [http service](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/script-functions-implemented-as-cfcs/http.html) functions. For example:

```
<cfscript>
secKey = "sk_test_xxxx";

/* create new http service */
httpService = new http();
httpService.setMethod("post");
httpService.setCharset("utf-8");
httpService.setUrl("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions");

/* add header */
httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Bearer " & secKey);

/* add params */ 
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="success_url",value="https://example.com/success");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="cancel_url",value="https://example.com/fail");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="payment_method_types[]",value="card");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][amount]",value="1000");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][currency]",value="usd");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][quantity]",value="1");
httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][name]",value="widget");

/* make the http call */
result = httpService.send().getPrefix();

/* parse json and print id */
chkSession = DeserializeJSON(result.fileContent);
writeoutput(chkSession.id)
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Perfect that got me to the next step, I do really appreciate the help I have two other bits I need to convert.

Comment: Im struggling with the other two parts, if you could help that would be great

Comment: The other part is just javascript! So there's no conversion, you just create your html page and include the session id created from the above server side checkout code.

Comment: I also recommend #stripe on https://webchat.freenode.net/ as a resource, a lot of developers hang out there

Comment: on there now would love to chat more