# Errors Coverting Stripe Javascript to CFscript errors

Tags: stripe-payments, cfml

I'm working with the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs)  received some help [converting a java example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58309934/can-you-convert-stripe-java-code-into-cfscript) making an http call. The top part of the code below is working. However when I make the last two pieces of code for the redirect, I think it struggles because it can not read variables made in cfscript.

This link explains what I'm trying to do https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/server using java and converting it.

```
<cfscript>
   secKey = "sk_test_********";

   /* create new http service */
   httpService = new http();
   httpService.setMethod("post");
   httpService.setCharset("utf-8");
   httpService.setUrl("https://api.stripe.com/v1/checkout/sessions");

   /* add header */
   httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Bearer " & secKey);

   /* add params */ 
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="success_url", value="https://example.com/success");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="cancel_url", value="https://example.com/fail");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="payment_method_types[]", value="card");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][amount]", value="1000");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][currency]", value="usd");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][quantity]", value="1");
   httpService.addParam(type="formfield",name="line_items[0][name]", value="widget");

   /* make the http call */
   result = httpService.send().getPrefix();

   /* parse json and print id */
   chkSession = DeserializeJSON(result.fileContent);
   writeoutput(chkSession.id);
</cfscript>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    const stripe = Stripe('pk_test_**********');
</script>
<script>
    const {error} = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
       // Make the id field from the Checkout Session creation API response
       // available to this file, so you can provide it as parameter here
       // instead of the {{CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}} placeholder.
       sessionId: '(chkSession.id)'
   })
   // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
   // error, display the localized error message to your customer
   // using `error.message`.
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have `chkSession` from the cfscript code and then need it available on the client-side. To do that you just need to output the js script with the variable output.

```
  sessionId: '<cfoutput>#chkSession.id#</cfoutput>'
```

If the variable is not available where you need to output it then add `request.` when setting and outputting it to place it into the request scope which is available from all code on the CF server running in the same request.